# Method Within a Method to replace a boolean statement

Tags: java, methods

As part of a homework assignment I need to use this method:

```
public boolean validIndex(int index)
    {
        if ((index >= 0) && (index <= files.size() - 1)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and I need to implement it in this method instead of the boolean if statement:

```
public void listFile(int index)
    {
        if(index >= 0 && index < files.size()) {
            String filename = files.get(index);
            System.out.println(filename);
        }
    }
```

How do I call the original method in the second one?

Answer (score 1):

Call `validIndex` inside `if` statement in `listFile` function

```
if(validIndex(index))
{
   String filename = files.get(index);
   System.out.println(filename);
}
```

So if the `validIndex` funtion returns `True` then this will be evaluated as
`if(True)` and the body of the function will be executed.

If the `validIndex` returns `False` then this will be `if(False)` and the function body will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
public void listFile(int index)
{
    if(validIndex(index)) { 
        String filename = files.get(index);
        System.out.println(filename);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the boolean value from said `validIndex` method and that value will determine the control flow of the if that it is being called by.

```
if(validIndex(index))
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that:

```
public void listFile(int index)
{
    if(validIndex(index)) { 
        String filename = files.get(index);
        System.out.println(filename);
    }
}
```

is not going to behave exactly the same as:

```
public void listFile(int index)
{
    if(index >= 0 && index < files.size()) {
        String filename = files.get(index);
        System.out.println(filename);
    }
}
```

because:

```
public boolean validIndex(int index)
{
    if ((index >= 0) && (index <= files.size() - 1)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

has a key difference: the "File no found" line.

By the way,

```
((index >= 0) && (index <= files.size() - 1))
```

and

```
 (index >= 0  &&  index <  files.size())
```

turn out to be the same even though they look different.